# "Right now in this room" or "Right now, in this room"?

Tags: commas

Is the comma after "*right now*" necessary in this sentence?

> "*Right now[,] in this room, blah, blah, blah*."

Would the writer choose to make it non-restrictive?

Comment: Don't assume that the writer would mean that.  These things aren't anything so formal as all that.

Comment: I don't understand.

Comment: Don't assume that the writer would automatically connect the command with restrictiveness.

Comment: Okay, but that wasn't what I was asking.

Comment: Commas are a style choice, not a law.

Answer (score 1):

Reference [Commas rule 4a](http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/commas.asp)

Both ways are fine depending on what the sentence needs to convey.  For example:

> Right now, in this room, the show is about to start

"Right now" is a prepositional phrase (used in the same way as the dependent clause in rule 4a of the reference above) and is separated with a comma.  This give emphasis, telling the reader that the important message in the sentence is the "at this time". The reader will pause at each comma.

> The meeting is taking place right now in this room

The important thing in this sentence is that "the meeting is taking place".  There is no comma in "right now in this room", the co-coordinating conjunction "in" is sufficient to hold the sentence together and there is no need for a pause.

> The meeting is taking place right now, in this room

The key message again is "right now".  The comma indicates a pause, lending emphasis to the face that the event is occurring "right now".  The fact that the meeting is occurring in this room is almost an aside, not important.

So both are fine, it really depends on what message the writer is trying to convey.

Comment: 'Right now'— which of them is a preposition?

Answer (score 0):

Adverbs have free mobility within a sentence. Single word adverbs don't generally require commas while modifying a verb an adjective or any other adverb in a sentence. Sentence adverbs, context adverbs, conjunctive adverb, adverbial phares of more than five words or series of prepositional phrases require commas after them when they begin the sentence. Often a comma after adverb phrases is needed to eliminate confusion.

- In the contest [,] entries were put alphabetically.

In the example sentence " right now in this room " is an adverbial phrase. " In this room" is very much an inseparable part of it. It is a complete whole; there is no need to think of the prepositional phrase, " in this room " in isolation. So a comma is not necessary at all.

Adverbs modify, fine-tune and provide highly specific meaning at the sentence level. Context, relevance and personas' attitude there and then may give rise to use of a comma otherwise felt unnecessary by language pundits.

Jerome K Jerome writes:

- As often as not he was sitting on it.(no comma)
- All the time, right in front of your noses--!(comma)

We are speaking of Uncle Podger in his frenzied search for day's newspaper. Comma and context go hand in hand. Podger has a licence to put a comma in between.